# Scroll Bar Not Showing in Business App - Cosmopolitan Theme

Tags: silverlight-4.0, scrollbar, business-application

Here is the style from the Styles.xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="PageScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-58,-15,-58,-15"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="58,0,58,0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
</Style>
```

Regardless of the size of the browser window, nor if I set the values to "Visible" I am not presented with a scroll bar. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fiddling with this and decided to try changing the order of the LayoutRoot Grid and the ScrollViewer and this seems to have fixed it.

I changed

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource PageScrollViewerStyle}">
...
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

to this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource PageScrollViewerStyle}">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
...
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```